# Drawing an arc using pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I need to draw some shapes on the screen using *pyqtgraph*.
I chose *pyqtgraph* over *matplotlib* because the former is way faster when a lot of shapes are present.
For lines polygons everything is ok, since I can simply plot multiple straight lines.
But how can I represent efficiently an arc?

I found out here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525279/pyqtgraph-how-do-i-plot-an-ellipse-or-a-circle) that the function **pyqtgraph.QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem()** allows me to draw a full ellipse.
But what if I just need an arc of that ellipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution where you can put two angles in degree and a direction for the arc (clockwise or counter clockwise). You can also put the radius. To translate the arc, you can just add two scalar for the x and y axis.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

def Get_Points(r, a1, a2, nbPoints,clockwise=True):
    a1_rad = np.radians(a1)
    if a1_rad <0:
        a1_rad += 2 * np.pi
    a2_rad = np.radians(a2)
    if a2_rad <0:
        a2_rad += 2 * np.pi

    if a1_rad > a2_rad:
        if clockwise:
            t= np.linspace( a1_rad,a2_rad, nbPoints)
        else:
            t = np.linspace(a2_rad, a1_rad - 2 * np.pi,nbPoints)
    else:
        if clockwise:
            t= np.linspace(a2_rad, a1_rad,nbPoints)
        else:
            t = np.linspace(a1_rad, a2_rad - 2 * np.pi, nbPoints)
    x = r * np.cos(t)
    y = r * np.sin(t)
    return x, y

win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="Plotting")
win.setFixedSize(500, 500)
p = win.addPlot(title='')
r = 10
a1 = 80
a2 = -200
x,y = Get_Points(r, a1, a2, 1000,clockwise=True)

c = pg.PlotCurveItem(x,y,cl=True)
p.setXRange(-1.5 * r, 1.5 * r, padding=0)
p.setYRange(-1.5 * r, 1.5 * r, padding=0)

p.addItem(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: That's a more complete solution, and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the position of some points on the arc and display them with a `PlotCurveItem`

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

t= np.arange(0,5*2*np.pi/6 ,0.01)
x = np.sin(t+0.5)
y = np.cos(t+0.5)
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="Plotting")
win.setFixedSize(500, 500)
p = win.addPlot(title='')
p.setXRange(-1.5, 1.5, padding=0)
p.setYRange(-1.5, 1.5, padding=0)


c = pg.PlotCurveItem(x,y)

p.addItem(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: This solution si exactly what I was looking for. However, there is an additional requirement: I need also to specify the direction of the arc. Given a center and two angles, there are actually two arcs that can satisfy the requirement: one clockwise and the other counterclockwise. Do you know how to add also this feature?